# C# Service Request

Tags: c#, web-services

I stack on Apple GSX Api request in c# project. Everything is ok but I cannot get response from api.
Certificates done, Static IPs have whitelisted.

Return this error when i request to "https://gsxapiut.apple.com/gsx-ws/services/emea/asp"

> {"An error occurred while making the HTTP request to
>   https://gsxapiut.apple.com/gsx-ws/services/emea/asp. This could be due
>   to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly
>   with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a
>   mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server."}

Request Function :

```
 public void Authenticate()
    {
        try
        {
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;               
            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://gsxapiut.apple.com/gsx-ws/services/emea/asp");               
            var sslCertFilename = "test.p12";
            var sslCertPassword ="xxxxx";
            GsxApi3.GsxWSEmeaAspPortClient service = new GsxApi3.GsxWSEmeaAspPortClient();

            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
            service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(
               sslCertFilename,
                sslCertPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

            var auth = new GsxApi3.authenticateRequestType()
            {
                languageCode = "EN",
                serviceAccountNo = "xxxxxxxxx",
                userId = "xxxxxxxxxxx",
                userTimeZone = "CET"
            };

            var session = service.Authenticate(auth);                
            var userSessionId = new GsxApi3.gsxUserSessionType { userSessionId = session.userSessionId };
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {


        }


    }
```

Comment: Problem solved. İf [userId] doesnt have required permisson of apple side , forcibly broking service request.